# Pass Javascript Output to PHP

Tags: javascript, curl

I am connecting to an API using PHP's CURL. The address or $url is what I need help with. Currently I have a script that runs when a user has submitted there investment form which then creates an "InvestmentID"

This investment ID is part of a JSON object where I can grab items such as investment amount.

Currently my code works it connects to the API using CURL on form submission but the bit I can't get my head around is how to pass the "InvestmentID" to the end of the $URL string such as

$url =  'https://sandbox.fundamerica.com/api/investments/' . $outputtedID;

Sorry about the repetitive code I have been working on it for a few hours now and aware it needs some healthy tidying up which I will do once I get this figured out.

1. User fills out form an "InvestmentID" is produced.
2. The "InvestmentID" appends to the end of the $URL string.
3. The CURL command stores the output in a javascript variable.

I really hope this makes sense. Please find my code below.

```
<script>    
      document.addEventListener('fa.investnow.success', function(e){
      var InvestorInvestmentID = e.investment_id;
      <?php
      $url =  'https://sandbox.fundamerica.com/api/investments/';
      $username = 'c7YU_vDAQmPrLkHCw6ydXRYKcrviev7U';
      $password = '';
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      //echo $output ;
      ?>
      var investmentReturn = 
      <?php echo $output; ?>;   
      console.log(investmentReturn);
      console.log(InvestorInvestmentID);
      });



      function doSomethingWithInvestmentId(InvestorInvestmentID){
      console.log(InvestorInvestmentID);
      <?php
      $url =  'https://sandbox.fundamerica.com/api/investments/';
      $username = 'c7YU_vDAQmPrLkHCw6ydXRYKcrviev7U';
      $password = '';
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      //echo $output ;
      ?>
      var investmentReturn = 
      <?php echo $output; ?>;   
      console.log(investmentReturn);
      };

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: `<?php echo '"' + $output + '"'; ?>;`

Comment: Yes the output is created via JS though so how do I store this as a PHP variable? e.g. var output = "5fg2553fgdfaddg". How do I then add this to the end of the $URL string?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Where do you need to add the URL?

Comment: Basically what I need is:

1. User submits form the "fa.investnow.success" creates an id.
2. I store this ID into a JS variable.
3. I pass this JS Variable to the end of the PHP $URL.
4. Grab the relevant API data.
5. Store to JS as object.

Comment: `3. I pass this JS Variable to the end of the PHP $URL` -- you can't pass a JS variable to PHP like that -- you need to SEND the data from JS to PHP by doing a POST or GET request.

Comment: Yeah :( I am open to other ideas though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion best solution will be to create separete JS and PHP file.

1. Create JS file which you'll use for getting investmentID and create and API call on your PHP file.

So you get your id

```
document.addEventListener('fa.investnow.success', function(e){
  var InvestorInvestmentID = e.investment_id; 
}
```

and then make call using jQuery

```
$.get( "test.php?id=" + InvestorInvestmentID );
```

2. Create your PHP file which will basicly just `$_GET` id and execute a API call on that external resources using CURL as you mentioned above.

> ```
>  // You get ID from URL 
>   $id = $_GET['id'];
>  // Rest of your code comes here
> ```

Comment: sounds like a good solution. My PHP isn't exactly amazing so when you say $_GET['id']; where is the "id" variable coming from?

Comment: from that AJAX request above, so this :
`$.get( "test.php?id=" + InvestorInvestmentID );`